# Tank Auth value, set_value, and form validation issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, tankauth

I'm using Tank Auth (it's working fine), but I can't get the form validation function to work when I include any value in the variable array along with set_value. I need these values as a label for form fields--they tells the user what to enter in the field.

How can I keep Tank Auth's form validation functionality AND use a value in the value field?

```
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login', 'Enter username'),
);
```

Comment: Downvoter, show yourself! There is nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this populates field values : `set_value('field_name');`

this shows individual errors: `form_errors('field_name');`

If you use html5, you can simply add a placeholder!

{ *placeholders should not be used as an alternative to labels!*}

```
$login = array(
    'name'  => 'login',
    'id'    => 'login',
    'value' => set_value('login'),
    'placeholder' => 'Enter Username',
    'required' => 'required'
);
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try this, but why shouldn't placeholder's be used as labels?

Comment: This worked! Accepted and upvoted. Would really like to know why placeholders shouldn't be used as labels, though.